# Ways to sort tags wherein no wiki

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Currently I am venturing to make our Tags informative. 
Although i can browse and see tags I wonder is there any ways i can sort tags having no wiki? just like unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome! Your efforts are appreciated.

I don't know of any way in the user interface to find tags with no wikis off-hand, aside from just browsing and manually checking on the [/tags](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags) page, which may suffice for this.

So, I went ahead and took the liberty of writing a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) query to find tags without wikis.

[You can find that query here.](http://data.stackexchange.com/patents/query/277446/tags-with-no-wikis)

As you may notice upon reading that query and its results, those are the tags for Ask Patents that currently have no tag wiki. Note, of course, that there are probably lots of tags with *bad* wikis, that aren't displayed there. Some of those may be higher priority than many of the ones returned by that query.

---

Just for the record, since we're talking about tag wikis, I figured I'd throw in a couple resources your way. You may or may not have already seen these:

- [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)
- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
- [How do I use tags?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/tag-use)

Some of those may contain redundant and/or irrelevant information, but when undertaking a goal like cleaning up the site, it's important to keep in mind the direction to aim for.

I'd probably shy away from getting too "trigger-happy" with writing tag wikis. Particularly here on Ask Patents, where the [privilege to create tags is inherent to any account](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), we tend to get a lot of posts with tags that aren't a great match for our indexing engines' main goals.

That's no big deal, but there's really no use in you wasting your time, writing a description for something that shouldn't really exist in the first place. So that's why I included the two articles on how to properly use tags here. The first step to writing any tag wiki will probably be establishing whether that tag should exist.

If you're positive that any you find shouldn't and if there aren't many questions using them, you can simply edit them away, and the system will delete them in due time. If you're unsure or if there *are* many questions using a tag, you're free to post here on Meta and ask for input. Such posts are often referred to as [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s.